# DHT22 issues using raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I am trying to read the temperature and humidity data in DHT22 sensor using Raspberry Pi 4 board by following the python scripts below

```
import Adafruit_DHT
DHT22Sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22

DHTpin = 16

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT22Sensor, DHTpin)

if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    print("Temp={0:0.1f}*C  Humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity))
else:
    print('Failed to get reading. Try again!')
```

However, when I tried to run the code, the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_DHT.py", line 6, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT22Sensor, DHTpin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 94, in read_retry
    humidity, temperature = read(sensor, pin, platform)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 81, in read
    return platform.read(sensor, pin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/Beaglebone_Black.py", line 202, in read
    match = re.match('GPIO([0123])_(\d+)', pin, re.IGNORECASE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 173, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does anyone why is it happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Adafruit_DHT package does not support the Raspberry Pi 4 - only up to Raspberry Pi 3b+. In your case it detects a Beaglebone Black.